# Connecting to SQL Server with Integrated Security within Windows container

Tags: sql-server, docker, active-directory, docker-for-windows, gmsa

I am working on being able to connect services hosted within a Windows container to SQL Server using Integrated Security.

As per the Microsoft documentation, I have created a grouped managed service account (gMSA), credentials spec and my container hosts have access to the gMSA - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts

I have been testing the connection by using the SQL Server PowerShell module within the following container:

```
docker run --security-opt "credentialspec=file://mygsma.json" -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell
```

**Problem:**

When running the container in *hyper-v* isolation mode, I get the following error SQL Server error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

If I run the container in *process* isolation mode, I am able to successfully login to SQL Server using the gMSA. As far as I'm aware there is nothing to suggest that Integrated authentication for hyper-v containers is not supported.

There was a bug which prevented you using gMSAs with Hyper-V isolated containers on Windows 10 versions 1703, 1709, and 1803. However, I'm using Windows 10 version 1809 and can confirm the gMSA can be accessed by the container.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've seen this page, since the bug you're talking about is mentioned there, but have you tried the testing steps on [Troubleshoot gMSAs for Windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-troubleshooting)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yep, I have followed the steps on that page and everything is working as expected.